# The sum of the real roots of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1$

Tags: polynomials, roots, quartics

Consider a polynomial $f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1$. The sum of the real roots of $f(x)$ lies in the interval ...

1. $(0,1)$
2. $(-1,0)$
3. $(-2,-1)$
4. $(1,2)$

Using Intermediate Value property, I know that one root exists between $0$ and $1$, but I am stuck here and can't do anything else.

Any hints on how should I proceed?

Comment: Hint: usa Vieta's formulas

Comment: @LeonardoVannini But that will give the sum of all the roots I want only the real roots and I don't even know how many real roots will the equation have.

Comment: Oops... Use derivative tests to draw a graph first...

Comment: @hellotinfish I tried that, $f'(x)$ is zero at some negative value but I don't know if f(x) will lie above or below the x-axis at that value, if it lies below then there are going be 2 real roots but if it lies above there will be 0 real roots.

Comment: why would you not know if $f(x)$ will lie above or below the $x$-axis?

Comment: @hellotinfish I don't know the exact value, I only know that it will be negative

Comment: Use estimation then. You dont need exact value.

Comment: The interval $(1,0)$ is empty!

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x-1.$$
Thus, $$f(0.5)f(0.6)<0$$ and $$f(-1.3)f(-1.2)<0,$$
which says that there are two roots:
$$x_1\in(0.5,0.6)$$ and
$$x_2\in(-1.3,-1,2)$$ and
$$x_1+x_2\in(-0.8,-0.6).$$
But $$f''(x)=12x^2+6x+2>0,$$
which says that $f$ is a convex function.

Thus, our equation has at most two roots and the answer is $3)$.

By the Descartes' rule of signs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs)

our equation has one positive root only and we can check a placing of the root by calculator or even by hand.

Comment: How did you think of those values?

Comment: @Gem I added something. See now.

Comment: For incognito, which up-votes my answers. If you indeed so like my solutions then do it please not so often, otherwise the system removes your work. Thank you!